# Creating a session in rest endpoint in spring

Tags: java, spring-security, session-cookies, jsessionid

I have created a endpoint which takes username and password and gives back the message wether the user is authenticated or not. 
As a effort to create a session for the user to maintain the session, I am calling `session.getSession(true)` so this is creating JSESSIONID cookie and setting in the response. But when I make a request to the protected endpoint the Spring security is redirecting to the endpoint which I have configured in the entry-point.

Please help what I am missing in creating a valid session. I can add more details if I am missing any to complete my question.

Comment: Do not want to guess so please paste the code along with you question to identify the root cause

Comment: Well I want to delete this Post. As it is not exact question which actually serves my purpose.My actual question would be If I use request.getSession(true) in the request can I let know the subsequent requests of spring that i have a valid session created? That is registering the session with spring.